# Are constants in module files supposed to be imported automatically?

Tags: raku

Given the module file `test.pm6`:

```
constant $AUTHOR='me';
```

And the script `test_script.p6`:

```
use lib '.';

use test;

my $AUTHOR = 'someone';
```

I get the following warning when I compile check `test_script.p6`:

```
perl6 -c test_script.p6
Potential difficulties:
    Redeclaration of symbol '$AUTHOR'
    at test_script.p6:5
    ------> my $AUTHOR⏏ = 'someone';
Syntax OK
```

However, simply changing `test.pm6` to one of the following makes this warning go away:

```
my $AUTHOR='me';
```

or

```
my constant $AUTHOR='me';
```

So, the question is whether constants should be imported automatically or is this a bug?

This is using [Rakudo Star 2017.01 Release Candidate 0](http://pl6anet.org/drop/rakudo-star-2017.01-RC0.tar.gz) installed on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a bug. Constants are `our` scoped by default and your constant in `test.pm6` is still in the mainline and so gets placed into the `GLOBAL` namespace and since it's an `our`, it's visible in your main script.

One way to avoid it is what you found: to use a `my` on constants/classes (as they default to `our`). Or conversely, to use an `our` on subroutines/variables that you want to make visible (as subs default to `my`).

Another way is to use, say, `unit module BlahBlah;` at the top of your module file, and then these symbols will be in `BlahBlah` namespace and not in the `GLOBAL` and so will not be visible in the main script directly (`our` symbols can still be accessed as `BlahBlah::whatever`)

P.S.: those on 2016 Rakudos won't observe this behaviour due to [lexical module loading bug](http://rakudo.org/2016/12/17/lexical-module-loading/), which got fixed only in 2017.01 compiler release (and was merged to master a couple of days after 2016.12 compiler release)

Comment: What is the relationship between `our` and `is export` ?

Comment: @BradClawsie, probably little, as `is export` code stuffs all the symbols into the importing package, whereas `our` makes things package scoped. What exactly that means when used in a mainline of a separate file... I'm not 100% sure.

I tried pinging the two people who would know, but they were AFK :)

The answer might also be slightly wrong. When I dump GLOBAL, I don't see the constant there, but instead in `MY`. And modules don't see it unless I `use` the file with the constant in them as well.

Comment: @BradClawsie, ah, nm, I got the explanation for the missing parts: it's not visible in all the modules because of precompilation as well as lexical module loading (which is why the symbol ends up in `MY::` instead of `GLOBAL`).